# Why should I prepend my custom attributes with "data-"?

Tags: html, attributes, custom-data-attribute

So any custom data attribute that I use should start with "data-":

```
<li class="user" data-name="John Resig" data-city="Boston"
     data-lang="js" data-food="Bacon">
  <b>John says:</b> <span>Hello, how are you?</span>
</li>
```

Will anything bad happen if I just ignore this? I.e.:

```
<li class="user" name="John Resig" city="Boston"
     lang="js" food="Bacon">
  <b>John says:</b> <span>Hello, how are you?</span>
</li>
```

I guess one bad thing is that my custom attributes could conflict with HTML attributes with special meanings (e.g., `name`), but aside from this, is there a problem with just writing "example_text" instead of "data-example_text"? (It won't validate, but who cares?)

Comment: The lang attribute is a default html attribute used for normal, spoken language. Using this in the current context will conflict with it's default behaviour and is a perfect example WHY you should use the data-* prefix.

Comment: Data attributes have a major drawback : you cannot see easily the values set with JavaScript to an element, it will not appear in the DOM unless you get them from JavaScript. That's why I always use the shorter form even if it's a bit risky

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are several benefit for keeping custom attributes prefixed with data-*.

1. It guarantees there will not be any clashes with extensions to HTML in future editions. This is a problem that has been encountered to some degree already with some of the new attributes introduced in HTML5, where existing sites were using attributes with the same name and expecting different and incompatible, custom behaviour. (e.g. the `required` attribute on `input` elements is known to have had some clashes on some popular websites in the past)
2. There is a convenient DOM API, [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), for accessing these attributes from scripts. It is now [supported in most browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset).
3. They provide a clear indication of which attributes are custom attributes, and which ones are standardised attributes.  This not only helps validators by allowing them to permit any attribute with data-* while still performing useful error checking for other attributes (e.g. to catch typos), it also helps make this aspect of the source code clearer to those reading it, including people who may work on a website after the original author.

Comment: I'm not holding my breath for (2), but (1) and (3) are good points

Comment: You're thinking of the days when browsers introduced new features only slowly, and only rarely.  These days most browsers support the `dataset` element property to simplify access to `data-*` properties: http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset

Comment: Is there a benefit to use dataset API?  It's much easier for me to see the raw form of the attribute both visually and with IDE colorization, i.e. `timeslot.attributes['data-week-number']` than `timeslot.dataset.weekNumber`.  Not to mention, easier to find/replace instances of it in the code.

Answer (score 8):

According to [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), the whole purpose of the addition of these custom data attributes to the HTML5 sepcs is to allow to embed custom data in HTML *while still being valid*.

If you don't care about validation (and, as you said, your custom attributes are not colliding with existing HTML attributes like `name`, `id`, `style`, etc.), then I guess you don't have to use the `data-` prefix. But considering that this is not a huge cost for writing valid, compatible code, I don't see why you wouldn't do it.

Comment: I guess my question is what value do I get from writing code that validates? (Given that having to type the meaningless "data-" prefix repeatedly isn't without cost)

Comment: For one thing, you get the fact that you can use a validator to find problems in your markup. This is a huge win when you're working on a page, because it's so easy to lose a closing div or something in a long page. 

If you periodically make sure your markup is valid, you're much more likely to be able to pinpoint inevitable errors soon after they appear.