# What's the correct way of passing attributes to the li tag?

Tags: html

I need to pass some values from the database to the `<li>` tag. Is the following acceptable and is it the correct way?

```
<li id='$current_row["RA_SUB_ID"]' component_name='$current_row["RA_SUB_NAME"]'    pub_id='$current_row["RA_SUB_PUBLIC_ID"]'>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom attributes - Yay or nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yay-or-nay)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, i will have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `li` tag only displays one text value (some browsers also support a value attribute). So it depends which one you want. You need to use the following syntax.

```
<li>$current_row["TEXT_YOU_WANT"]</li>
```

Optionally you can set an ID to programatically access the element (using client side script, such as JavaScript)

```
<li id="$current_row["ID_YOU_WANT"]">$current_row["TEXT_YOU_WANT"]</li>
```

Now if you'd like to set more data to access on the client side, you can use the `data-` custom attributes.

```
<li id="$current_row["ID_YOU_WANT"]" data-foo="$current_row["FOO_YOU_WANT"]">$current_row["TEXT_YOU_WANT"]</li>
```

These can be accessed in jQuery usign the [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function.

Comment: i need to pass several values from the database and retrieve them on the client side using javascript and i believe the data i want to pass has to be in the form of custom attributes. The thing is am not sure whether that's a good practice, although it seems to be working fine

Comment: If you use the `data-` prefix for your custom attributes, I personally think that's fine. Other's disagree. Another option would be to hold JavaScript arrays for all your data and use the `li` id to index?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.., i think i might go for the data- prefix

Comment: You're welcome :) It might be worth having a glance through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450585/why-should-i-prepend-my-custom-attributes-with-data too. Some good explanations as to why it's better to use that prefix.