# Why should I use "data-" in my attributes or dashes in my tags?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute, custom-tag

1. According to many recent HTML specs, when we are using custom attributes (meaning any attributes not defined in the spec), we should prefix them with `data-`. However, I see no reason to have to do this (unless you require perfectly valid HTML, obviously). Pretty much all current browsers correctly ignore custom attributes, meaning no conflicts except with identically-named attributes from others' code, and we can ignore even this with custom prefixes or something similar (as suggested on the [AngularJS directive page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)). What, if any, other benefits are there? This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450585/why-should-i-prepend-my-custom-attributes-with-data), at least [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yea-or-nay), but both are pretty old.
2. I forget where I read it, but some guide said custom HTML tags need dashes, and single-word tags aren't valid. First of all, why? Second, should we do this, and why (besides being valid)? Would there be any problem with underscores or camelCase, etc.? Also, conflicts with existing elements shouldn't be a problem, if, like with `data` attributes, you prefix or suffix them, etc. See the [Angular directive page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) again.

I'm sure all these questions have been asked before, but I'm combining them into one. Is that a good idea (quick, someone ask on Meta)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data-*` attributes have two advantages:

1. It is a convention meaning other programmers will understand quickly that it is a custom attribute.
2. You get a DOM Javascript API for free: [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset). If you use jQuery, it leverages this to populates the keys and values you find with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

The reason for the `-` in custom element names is for [two basic reasons](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/):

1. It is a quick way for the HTML parser to know it is a custom element instead of a standard element.
2. You don't run into the issue of a new standard element being added with the same name which would cause conflict if you register a custom Javascript prototype for the DOM element.

Should you use your own custom element name? Right now it is so new that don't expect it to be fully supported. Let's say it does work. You have to balance the issue of the extra complexity with the benefit. If you can get away with a classname, then use a classname. But if you need a whole new element with a custom Javascript DOM prototype for the element, then you may have a valid usage of it.

Comment: For `data-` #1, idk, "data" just seems like an odd choice. I guess that is another reason to use it, because it sticks out like a sore thumb in HTML code. For custom `dash` elements (can that be a new name for them?), #2, see what I said about `data` attributes. You could have a prefix or something. I will update my question.

Comment: The article you linked to was the article I was thinking of. The "So the parser knows it's not a standard element" reason doesn't make sense to me, though. Can you explain?

Comment: The browser parses the HTML code into various models and objects so we have a webpage. Some of those models are behind the scenes, whereas other parts we can interact with through Javascript and CSS. Many of the elements don't have all that much difference between each other except for some default styles (<span> vs <div> vs <p>). But some do have special properties such as: <video>, <img>, <input>, <textarea>, <canvas>, etc. Some of those special properties are behind the scenes such as decoding a video file and then some of them have special Javascript methods such as the <canvas>.

Comment: The reason the browser wants to know if the element is custom is because it will go ahead and look for the customized Javascript DOM prototype for the custom element if you define it. By knowing the name is custom, it then knows it may have to apply a custom Javascript prototype to it later on.

Comment: OK, so the custom for the tag is a precautionary measure, but is there a reason for the `data-` like that? Also, it may know beforehand if you give it & not know if you don't, but are there any performance improvements etc.? How about if you use something like AngularJS, does it do all the heavy lifting?

Comment: The back story of `data-` is that it was designed based on how developers were doing. Developers need to add data for JS for elements. Various solutions came out. A common one was custom attributes. Libraries such as jQuery had helpers to add custom data to elements from the JS. By merging the two patterns, we get `data-*` attributes that are then parsed into the `dataset` attribute on elements. I would be surprise if there are performance gains by allowing the parser handle the `dataset` creation instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: As for AngularJS, I'm not sure why they went custom (they do support `data-` version). Some say it is domain specific, meaning you aren't writing a webpage, you are writing an AngularJS app. If they can get enough people onboard to treat is a pseudo-standard, then you avoid the confusion of custom attributes appearing willy-nilly to others. Imagine you take over a project from someone who used custom attributes but you can't ask them what they are. You'll probably be scratching you head despite how obvious the other person thought they were. At least with `data-`, you have an idea what it is.