# Display an alert with javascript if checkbox value is different from original checked/unchecked state

Tags: javascript, checkbox

So basically I have several checkboxes that are checked or unchecked, depending on values in a mysql database. Their checked/unchecked values are also stored in an attr called "def" which is either 0, or checked. I also have some javascript I have written that applies an attr to the checkboxes called "checked", which changes when you check and uncheck boxes. So what I want to do is compare these two values in javascript, when the checked attr is changed when the user clicks on a checkbox, if the checked attr is true and def is 0, then it should send out an alert saying the value is different from the default value, otherwise it should do nothing if def is 0, and checked is false. I am learning javascript and this is what I have so far in JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FCrSg/89/

Here is my HTML checkbox:

```
<input class='checkboxstatus' def='0' type=checkbox></input>
```

and my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.checkboxstatus').click(function(){
    this.setAttribute('checked',this.checked);
    if($(this).checked && $(this).def == '0'){
    //checkbox has changed
    alert('checkbox has changed from original value');
    }
 });
 });
```

Comment: `this.setAttribute('checked',this.checked);` -- Hmm, seems redundant considering that is the default behavior of the checkbox - just saying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax would be

```
if (this.checked && $(this).attr("def") == 0)
```

However, `def` isn't a recognized or valid attribute, it should be `data-def` to be completely valid. Then you can do:

```
if (this.checked && $(this).data("def") == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for me. I took your advice and used data-def.

Comment: @John -- Glad to hear it! Be sure to mark the answer if this accomplished everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cEGks/1/.

You need to use the jQuery function `.attr()` ([documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)) to get the `def` attribute. I also changed it to `data-def` for [better browser support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450585/why-should-i-prepend-my-custom-attributes-with-data) and broke the logic into another function for readability.

You also do not need to set an attribute `checked` on the checkbox. You can just use jQuery's `.is(':checked')` to check if it is checked.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<input class='checkboxstatus' data-def='1' type="checkbox" />
```

JS:

```
$('.checkboxstatus').click(function(){
    if(checkboxChangedFromOriginal($(this))) {
        alert('checkbox has changed from original value');
    }
 });

function checkboxChangedFromOriginal(checkbox) {
 return (checkbox.is(':checked') && checkbox.attr('data-def') == '0') ||
     (!checkbox.is(':checked') && checkbox.attr('data-def') == '1');  
}
```