# why do we need prefix "data" for custom data attributes in html5

Tags: jquery, html, w3c, custom-data-attribute

Is there any reason to use data-attribute for custom data attributes on html5 elements? I remember using custom data attributes without using data prefix and I think that did work alright.

Can someone please correct me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I prepend my custom attributes with "data-"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450585/why-should-i-prepend-my-custom-attributes-with-data)

Answer (score 2):

Abridged version of [the answer by @Lachlan Hunt to the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2451188/1026):

- It guarantees there will not be any clashes with extensions to HTML in future editions.
- More convenient DOM API for accessing these attributes from scripts.
- They provide a clear indication of which attributes are custom attributes, and which ones are standardised attributes.

Comment: doesn't it make 'data' prefix irrelevant can that be done with using some other prefix as well. i've used many other custom html attributes.

Comment: If you don't need the `dataset` APIs and pick a unique prefix, sure.